# Qual IDE usar para C#/C++?

Tags: c#, ide

Bom pessoal, quero me inserir no mundo da programação cujo usuários finais são os usuários de Windows. Já mexo com Java e tenho uma noção de programação, só o que queria saber mesmo é uma IDE que eu possa usar pra programar C#/C++. Busco a opinião de vocês pra isso. Eu procuro uma IDE muito pela facilidade que eu tive no Java, já que usando o Eclipse, que é a IDE que eu uso, é extremamente fácil criar um arquivo .JAR. Eu busco uma IDE que tenha a mesma facilidade de criar um arquivo .EXE por exemplo, além dos auxiliares de código que tem na maioria das IDEs, bem como o Eclipse. Agradeço a todos desde já!

Comment: Como "baseada em opiniões"? Só existem 3 IDEs para usar com C#/C++. E ele perguntou qual ele pode usar, e não "qual é a melhor" ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 4):

Aconselho utilizar o Visual Studio 2017, é um IDE fácil manuseio e muito fácil para quem esta começando a programar em C#/C++

Nesse link você pode baixar a IDE

https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br%2F

Comment: Acabei de baixar. Eu vi na instalação algo sobre Windows, aquilo acrescentou 9GBs de download na instalação, optei por não baixar. Tem problema?

Comment: Não,no  visual studio que esta instalando tem as opções de você baixar ou não os pacotes que vem com ele, fica a seu critério